# Circular Dependencies in Eclipse Platform

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to add the Eclipse Platform to my Maven project and stumbled over something very weird.

There is the plug-in [`org.eclipse.swt`](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/platform/org.eclipse.swt/3.109.0/org.eclipse.swt-3.109.0.pom), which has a dependency `org.eclipse.swt.${osgi.platform}`, where `${osgi.platform}` can be any of the following:

- `cocoa.macosc.cocoa`
- `gtk.linux.aarch64`
- `win32.win32.x86_64`

However if you check the *pom.xml* of [`org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64`](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/platform/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64/3.108.0/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64-3.108.0.pom) you learn that this project has a dependency to `org.eclipse.swt`. Which forms a nice dependency circle, which is not allowed in Maven nor in OSGi.

Consequently I'm getting a `StackOverflowError`, but only if I try to use the `maven-dependency-plugin` with `-Dosgi.platform=win32.win32.x86_64`.

If I don't use that parameter I get the following exception:

```
No versions available for org.eclipse.platform:org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.aarch64:jar:[3.105.2,3.105.2]
```

(Which is probably okay, because I guess that Linux is the default value, but it doesn't apply to me, since I've got a Windows PC.)

I can't exclude the dependency either, e.g. with:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.aarch64</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

I get the same error messages as above with that approach.

I'm wondering how the Eclipse guys even managed to release that mess, but more importantly: How do I build  against a Maven project with circular dependencies like this?

Comment: Eclipse-based applications (which are OSGi-based) are built via Tycho using p2 repositories, not Maven repositories. Dependencies are defined differently in OSGi and Maven. The plugins available from Maven Central are indented to be used in plain Java, not in OSGi applications.

Comment: @howlger Both projects do not define a  `<packing>` tag (as seen in the links), so both are plain Maven, not Tycho. I have a plain Maven project, too. This should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: You cannot add the Eclipse platform to a non-Tycho Maven project. The dependencies in Maven and in OSGi are technical differently and cannot be mixed: in Maven dependencies are only required to build an application, whereas in OSGi bundles can be installed, started and stopped at runtime and there is versioning not only on bundle/JAR level but also on package level.

Comment: @howlger Just so I understand you correctly. These Maven artifacts with their Maven *pom.xml* that are in Maven Central... are not allowed to be used with Maven?

Comment: These Maven artifacts can be used in non-Tycho Maven to build plain (non-OSGi) Java application. For example, you can use Eclipse JGit, SWT or the Eclipse Java compiler also in plain Java application.

Comment: @howlger Okay. Let's say I want to use `org.eclipse.swt` in a non-OSGi Java application. How do I add the dependency to Maven, since it has a circular dependency with its OS fragment?

Comment: For a non-OSGi program you don't use the SWT plug-ins. SWT is also available as plain Jars (for example in the [Eclipse Project downloads](https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.10-201812060815/))

Comment: @SteffiS. I didn't manage SWT via Maven right away either. I use JGit via Maven in a plain Java application without any problems. Maybe something went wrong publishing SWT to Maven Central. In this case, it would be good if you report it to Eclipse.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks. We don't *actually* have a plain Java application. We have thousands of problems because Maven and Tycho do not work together, which spawned processes too complicated to allow agile programming, so my job is to evaluate if we can use one of those (Maven or Tycho) to build all of our projects. But I guess if we can't use the Eclipse platform in Maven it's not looking good.

Comment: @SteffiS. Tycho is Maven and [used to build the IDE packages](https://hudson.eclipse.org/packaging/job/simrel.epp-tycho-build/). For example, the [`pom.xml` for the Eclipse platform can be found here](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.git/tree/pom.xml). The Maven plug-in Tycho uses one or more p2 repositories to build e. g. an RCP application. A Maven repository does not contain enough metadata e. g. to resolve dependencies defined via `Import-Package`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong place. Eclipse artifacts are published in Eclipse p2 repositories. In addition, some **Eclipse artifacts** will be published **in Maven repositories for use in plain (non-Eclipse based) Java applications** which cannot be used to build Eclipse-based applications. Something seems to have gone wrong publishing Eclipse SWT to Maven Central causing the circular dependencies. Please report this to Eclipse.

The [Eclipse IDE packages](https://hudson.eclipse.org/packaging/job/simrel.epp-tycho-build/) are built with the **Maven plug-in [Tycho](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/)**. See for example the [`pom.xml` file for the Eclipse platform](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.git/tree/pom.xml) or here the [parent `pom.xml` for all IDE packages](https://git.eclipse.org/c/epp/org.eclipse.epp.packages.git/tree/pom.xml). **Tycho uses one or more Eclipse p2 repositories** to resolve dependencies. A Maven repository would not work to resolve `Import-Package` dependencies or product configurations, for example. In a Maven repository, an artifact has a version, while in a p2 repository also Java packages of the same JAR can have different versions. In a Maven Tycho `pom.xml` only the p2 repositories have to be specified, the dependencies are already declared in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`, `feature.xml` and `*.product` files.